# Why if condition fails to execute?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a function **showWorthSum()** to return the sum of an array. It does but I have also put a condition if an element of an array is a number then it should be calculated only and rest should be skipped but still, it goes inside the if block in case of NaN and makes the whole result NaN. Why ?

```
function addWorth()
{    
    var table1= document.getElementById("tableNetWorths");

    var rowCount1= table1.rows.length;

    //var row1= table1.insertRow(rowCount1);

   var arr= [];

   for(var count = 0; count < rowCount1; count++)
   {    
        arr.push(table1.rows[count].cells[1].innerHTML);          
   }

   arr.shift();
   return arr;
} 

function showWorthSum()
{
    var returnedArr= addWorth();

    //returnedArr.push(addWorth());

     totalWorth= 0;

    var arrCount= returnedArr.length;

    for(var count = 0; count < arrCount; count++)
    {    
            if(typeof(parseInt(returnedArr[count])) == 'number')
            {
                totalWorth= parseInt(totalWorth)+ parseInt(returnedArr[count]); 
                //document.write(returnedArr[count]);

            }
    }

    return parseInt(totalWorth);
}
```

**array:** {100.200. 'asdadasd', 322, 22}

**Button:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.write(showWorthSum())" type="button">Show Sum</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead `isNaN(parseInt(returnedArr[count])) === false`

Although `NaN` by definition is `Not A Number`, `typeof NaN` is `number`

So to check if a variable is a number use `isNaN(value) === false` or `!isNaN(value)`

Examples:

- `isNaN(5) => false`
- `isNaN("5") => false`
- `isNaN("-5") => false`
- `isNaN(true) => false`
- `isNaN(false) => false`
- `isNaN({}) => true`
- `isNaN(NaN) => true`
- `isNaN("test") => true`
- `isNaN("5test") => true`
- `isNaN("test5") => true`

So you could also use `!isNaN(returnedArr[count])` to make it shorter

Comment: so what's the proper syntax ?

Comment: sorry, but still NaN

Comment: Do you have to parse it? Can you not just check the type of whatever you got in the array?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: isNan is not defined

Comment: @Covert it's `isNaN` not `isNan`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "typeof(parseInt(returnedArr[count])) == 'number'", you can use isFinite(returnedArr[count]).

```
isFinite('foo')
false

isFinite('10')
true

isFinite(10)
true

isFinite('898.0900')
true
```